# Finding prime number using BlockingQueue in Java with multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I've implemented a multi thread program using BlockingQueue to test for a number is prime or not.

The requirement is the program will prompt user to input a number and then the program will print every prime number from 2 to inputted number from user in ascending order.

I have 3 class: **NumberEnumerationTask** for initialize BlockingQueue contains all numbers to be check, **PrimeRunner** for check the number is prime or not, **PrimeChecker** for the main class.

***NumberEnumerationTask.java***

```
package multithread;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class NumberEnumerationTask implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    private Integer maximum;
    public static Integer DUMMY = new Integer(0);

    public NumberEnumerationTask(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue, Integer maximum) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
           enumerate();
           queue.put(DUMMY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Create a BlockingQueue contain Integer number from 1 to maximum.
    * @throws InterruptedException
    */
    private void enumerate() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 2; i < maximum; i++) {
           queue.put(i);
        }
    }
}
```

***PrimeRunner.java***

```
package multithread;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class PrimeRunner implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public PrimeRunner(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                Integer checkNumber = queue.take();
                if (checkNumber == NumberEnumerationTask.DUMMY) {
                    queue.put(checkNumber);
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    checkPrimeNumber(checkNumber);
                }
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkPrimeNumber(Integer number) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                queue.remove(number);
                break;
            } 
        }
        if (isPrime == true) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
            queue.remove(number);
        }
    }
}
```

***PrimeChecker.java***

```
public class PrimeChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter maximum number to check: ");
        Integer number = sc.nextInt();
    
        BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(number);
    
        NumberEnumerationTask initialize = new NumberEnumerationTask(queue, number);
        new Thread(initialize).start();
    
        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
            new Thread(new PrimeRunner(queue)).start();
        }
    
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

The **DUMMY** variable is to signal completion.

When I run the program, sometime it's not print in ascending order, sometime it does.

> Enter maximum number to check: 100
>
> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
>
> Enter maximum number to check: 100
>
> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 41 43 47 37 59 61 53 67 71 73 79 83 89 97

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PrimeChecker`, the following code is the cause:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
    new Thread(new PrimeRunner(queue)).start();
}
```

You create multiple `PrimeRunner` instances and a thread for each of them, so something like below can happen:

1. PrimeRunner in thread 1 takes 5.
2. PrimeRunner in thread 2 takes 7.
3. PrimeRunner in thread 2 prints 7. (PrimeRunner in thread 1 is still checking...)
4. PrimeRunner in thread 1 prints 5.

If you run a single `PrimeRunner` you can avoid such cases and it works as you expected.
If you still want to run multiple `PrimeRunner` surrounding the following part by `synchronized` block with an object in a static field of `PrimeRunner` should solve the problem:

```
Integer checkNumber = queue.take();
if (checkNumber == NumberEnumerationTask.DUMMY) {
    queue.put(checkNumber);
    done = true;
} else {
    checkPrimeNumber(checkNumber);
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand the problem now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Thread safety is the major issue. In your code, queue is shared among threads which is being processed without any synchronization mechanism hence data corruption likely to happen hence unpredictable result. If you run it multiple times you might get different results.

Multi-threading could be used for prime check to speed up the main goal i.e. prime finding which could be achieved by splitting the big number N into multiple parts and individual thread would work upon these parts and one thread to aggregate the results.

Comment: BlockingQueue is designed to be used by multi threads without external synchronization.

Comment: you missing the point. Calling individual methods like take and put will be thread safe but operation involving calls to different methods is not atomic.

Comment: Of course not. Anyway data corruption never happens, right?

Comment: Ah, missed that always its new instance of PrimeNumber is being created. Initially i thought its same PrimeNumber is shared hence suspected take() and put() two separate instructions might cause the issue.